# Positive integral on open intervals implies positivity almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ be a non-negative, Borel-measurable, and integrable function (with respect to the Lebesgue measure). Suppose that $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ implies that $$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x>0.$$ Does it necessarily follow that $f$ is positive almost everywhere?

I conjecture the answer is pretty straightforward (I know the converse is true) but it is eluding me right now for some reason. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a Cantor set of positive measure and $f=\chi_{\mathbb R \setminus C}$. Then $f=0$ on $C$ which has positive measure. If $\int_a^{b} f =0$ then $f=0$ a.e. on $(a,b)$ which means almost all points of $(a,b)$ are in $C$.  Since $C$ is closed this implies $[a,b] \subseteq C$. But $C$ contains no non-degenerate interval.

Comment: Thank you for this clever yet simple counterexample!